# What is the best way to read only one line of a big file in order to avoid memory problems?

Tags: java, file

I don't want to have the file in memory and those kind of things. Is it possible to read only the first line of a CSV without loading the full file in memory? Maybe using scanner approach?

It is just header checking!

Comment: that's what the input streams do for you

Comment: You can use [FileIterator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/libs/ant/xref/org/apache/commons/jelly/tags/ant/FileIterator.html)

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI No you can't. '`FileIterator` is an iterator over a number of *files* from a collection of `FileSet` instances.' It isn't a solution to this problem.

Comment: @EJP my bad it's the [LineIterator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html) I used to use it for file  over 2 Gb :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BufferedReader has an API to read only one line. Under the hood it buffers slightly more, but in general, you don't need to worry about it. This is the idiom I usually use:

```
String fileName = "..."; // use an actual file name :)
try (final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
    // try-with-resources idiom for auto-closing the readers
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Here you can deal with the line
        // Caveat: the line breaks are stripped.
        // So now you don't know if it was \r, '\n or both.
        System.out.println("--> read a line: " + line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // You might throw it too, or use a logger. Just don't hide it silently
    // because that makes debugging difficult.
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `BufferedReader.readLine()`. It won't buffer more than about 4K characters.

Comment: This is really the right answer.  The buffering reads blocks, which is the most hardware efficient way to read most files.  The readline() assures that you don't load the entire file as you fetch a bit of it into your processing loop.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [LineIterator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html), it answers perfectly your needs.

According to documentation, all you need is:

```
final File myFile = ... //A way to get your file
final LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(myFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        final String line = it.nextLine();
        // whatever you need to do..
    }
} finally {
    it.close();
}
```

Good  luck.